# MapStruct bulk conversion with @aftermapping

Tags: mapstruct

I want to apply a decoration using a dedicated @AfterMapping after the single item conversion of a DTO and another dedicated @AfterMapping when dealing with its collection conversion flavor but not both.

```
public abstract CatUI convert(Cat cat);
public abstract List<CatUI> convert(List<Cat> cats);


@AfterMapping
public void populateCatName(Cat cat, @MappingTarget CatUI catUI) {
     String name = _someRemoteService.getCatName(catUI.getId());
     catUI.setName(name);
}

@AfterMapping
public void populateCatNames(List<Cat> cats, @MappingTarget List<CatUI> catUIs) {
     Map<Integer,String> idToNameMap = _someRemoteService.getCatNames(catUIs.stream().map((c) -> c.getId() ).collect(Collectors.toList());
     catUIs.forEach((c) -> c.setName(idToNameMap(c.getId())));
}
```

I don't want populateCatName to be called when dealing with List conversion and hence duplicate my decoration.

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 5):

With 1.1.0.Final you will have to define 2 entry points (Mappers) one with the conversion on list and the other one without it.

I would suggest you try out the new 1.2.0.Beta2. With that one you can use the new `@Context`.

You can have an interface like:

```
public interface CatMappingContext {

    @AfterMapping
    public default void populateCatName(Cat cat, @MappingTarget CatUI catUI) {
        //nothing per default
    }

    @AfterMapping
    public void populateCatNames(List<Cat> cats, @MappingTarget List<CatUI> catUIs) {
        //nothing per default
    }
}
```

And 2 implementations:

```
public class SingleMappingContext implements CatMappingContext {

    @AfterMapping
    public void populateCatName(Cat cat, @MappingTarget CatUI catUI) {
        String name = _someRemoteService.getCatName(catUI.getId());
        catUI.setName(name);
    }
}

public class ListMappingContext implements CatMappingContext {

    @AfterMapping
    public void populateCatNames(List<Cat> cats, @MappingTarget List<CatUI> catUIs) {
        Map<Integer,String> idToNameMap = _someRemoteService.getCatNames(catUIs.stream().map((c) -> c.getId() ).collect(Collectors.toList());
        catUIs.forEach((c) -> c.setName(idToNameMap(c.getId())));
    }
}
```

Finally your mapper can look like:

```
public interface CatMapper {

    public CatUI convert(Cat cat, @Context CatMappingContext context);
    public List<CatUI> convert(List<Cat> cats, @Context CatMappingContext context);
}
```

You will then need to call your methods with the correct instance of the context `SingleMappingContext` or the `ListMappingContext`.

Comment: "You will then need to call your methods with the correct instance of the context" What would this look like in practice?

Comment: Something like `mapper.convert(catUI, new SingleMappingContext())` or `mapper.convert(catUIs, new ListMappingContext())`