# Mapstruct: passing one additional parameter in order to propagate it

Tags: java, mapstruct

`MyOM` and `MyEntity` objects have an id as a field
The function `map()` works. If I set the id parameter, then my MyEntity in `map()` receives this parameter.
I want to do the same thing with `mapDTOs()`. When it receives a value for id it must be propagated to all calls of `map()` during the loop.

How can I do this?

```java
@Mapping(target = "id", expression = "java(id)")
MyEntity map(MyOM om, String id);

@Mapping(target = ??, expression = ??)
List<MyEntity> mapDTOs(List<MyOM> dtos, String id);
```

Comment: My theory is: you can call both methods same (both called map) and the one that receives the list parameter will invoke the other; you can check if i'm correct checking the generated java file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional parameter should be annotated with `@Context` if meant to be passed to other mapping methods. The annotation was introduced in the 1.2 version, more info can be found in [MapStruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.4/api/org/mapstruct/Context.html).

Your method should be declared without any `@Mapping` annotation as:

```java
List<MyEntity> mapDTOs(List<MyOM> dtos, @Context String id);;
```

Since `@Context` parameters are not meant to be used as source parameters, a proxy method should be added to point MapStruct to the right single object mapping method to make it work.

```java
default MyEntity mapContext(MyOM om, @Context String id) {
    return map(om, id);
}
```

In case there is no proxy method, MapStruct would generate a new method for mapping a single object without mapping `id` because the existing one doesn't contain a second parameter marked as `@Context`.

This solution is simple but perhaps doesn't use `@Context` in the right way, for a better understanding of `@Context` usage check [Filip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44208762/10231374).